# Querystring url encode

Tags: php

i am getting a querystring parameter like companyname=Larson&tubro. Its a single string. But my script is just breaking it after '&'. What is the solution to take this as a single string in PHP. I tried like the below:

```
 <A onclick="window.open('comparitive_files/price_add.php?supplier_name= + urlencode({$supplier_name})&amp;tender_id={$tender_id}','mywindow','width=1200,height=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')" 
  href="#">
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using.  It will make it easier to debug the issue.

Comment: You are trying to use php functions in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use php functions outside of php. Try something like this.

```
echo '<A onclick="window.open(\'comparitive_files/price_add.php?supplier_name='.urlencode($supplier_name).'&tender_id='.$tender_id.',\'mywindow\',\'width=1200,height=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes\')" href="#">';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
 urlencode($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlencode` for encoding

```
 urlencode($companyname);
```

and `urldecode` for decoding

```
 urldecode($companyname)
```

Answer (score -1):

`&` is used to seperate variables in a querystring. Instead use `&amp;`.

To prevent any other illegal characters from getting in your querystring, use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: This companyname that is 'Larson&tubro' is coming from mysql db and i dont have control over it.

Comment: You have control over when you put it in the url right? use something like `'companyname=' + urlencode(databaseoutput)`

Comment: i try to give the said urlencode like this..<A onclick="window.open('comparitive_files/price_add.php?supplier_name= + urlencode({$supplier_name})&amp;tender_id={$tender_id}','mywindow','width=1200,height=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')"  href="#">......But not working

Comment: The &amp; you use should be an & in this case, since tender_id is actually a separate variable. Do you have some bigger example? The line where you print this?

Comment: In your example you are trying to use urlencode outside of php. Try using this: `<A onclick="window.open('comparitive_files/price_add.php?supplier_name=<?= urlencode($supplier_name) ?>&tender_id={$tender_id}','mywindow','width=1200,h‌​eight=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')" href="#">`